# Kibana dashboard data not showing

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm new to kibana, I linked the elasticsearch and kibana. I created the dashboard
[Dashboard with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6Cn5.png)

Next day, I'm accessing that dashboard, but it shows empty dashboard

[dashboard without data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixwVZ.png)

where I'm making the mistake?

Comment: There can be multiple reasons. Hints: 1) There is a time filter in kibana (adjust that). 2) Check if documents were indexed during the time range for which kibana is generating the dashboard.